# How to resize codemirror instance to the full height of parent object?

Tags: extjs, codemirror

I use `CodeMirror` in my `ExtJS` application. I do it like this:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
   layout:'border',
   items:[{
      region:'center',
      layout:'fit',
      border:false,
      dockedItems:[{
         xtype:'toolbar',
         items:[{
             xtype:'button',
             text:'push me!'
         }]
      }],
      html:'<textarea name="code" id="code"></textarea>',
      listeners:{
         render:function(){
             CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"),{
                 lineNumbers:true,
                 //fullScreen:true,
                 mode:{name:'javascript',globalVars:true}
             });
         }
      }
    }]
 });
```

The problem is `textarea` has some fixed height, defined in the library. So, even though, I add `width` and `height` parameters, or `style:height:100%` to the element, it has no effect. And if I use `fullScreen` option, then my `textarea` even hides the `toolbar` at the top.

**EDIT**

I did it, using css:

```
.CodeMirror {
       width: 100% !important;
       height: 100% !important;
  }
```

Though, I found a bug in the library. If you put a cursor at the last line inside `textarea` and hit `Enter`, then elements above that `textarea` are corrupted.

**EDIT. Complete test-case**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .CodeMirror {
       width: 100% !important;
       height: 100% !important;
  }     
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/ext-5.0.1/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/pages/lib/js/codemirror-4.7/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/pages/lib/js/codemirror-4.7/addon/display/fullscreen.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ext-5.0.1/build/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ext-5.0.1/build/packages/ext-locale/build/ext-locale-ru.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/pages/lib/js/codemirror-4.7/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/pages/lib/js/codemirror-4.7/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/pages/lib/js/codemirror-4.7/addon/display/fullscreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var MYAPP={
       CM:{},
       setCodeMirror:function(obj){
          this.CM=obj;
       },
       getCodeMirror:function(){
          return this.CM;
       }
   }

   Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true, disableCaching:true});

   Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux','/static/ext-5.0.1/examples/ux');

   Ext.require(['*']);

   Ext.onReady(function(){ 

       Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

       Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
           layout:'border',
           items:[{
               region:'center',
               layout:'fit',
               border:false,
               dockedItems:[{
                   xtype:'toolbar',
                   items:[{
                       xtype:'button',
                       icon:'/static/app/img/save.png',
                       tooltip:'Сохранить',
                       handler:function(){
                       // This tabpanel is corrupted when you hit Enter  
                       }
                   }]
               }]
           }]
       });

   });      

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<br/><br/>
<textarea id="code" name="code">...Write here a lot of text, so that the last line will be beyond visible arear of the screen... Then scroll down, put cursor to the last line and hit Enter. You will see that the tabpanel with a button is corrupted</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   MYAPP.setCodeMirror(CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"),{
       lineNumbers:true,
       mode:{name:'javascript',globalVars:true}
   }));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using html textarea, instead you could have used ExtJS text area, http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/docs/Ext.form.field.TextArea.1/

Answer (score 1):

First, the `<textarea>` tag is hidden if you convert it to a CodeMirror instance, so indeed, styling the textarea will do nothing.

Secondly, CodeMirror does definitely not generally corrupt a document if you press enter on the last line. This is probably something about your setup. If you create a minimal HTML page that demonstrates the issue, and submit an issue in the CodeMirror [bug tracker](https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror/issues), I can probably give you a solution.

Comment: I provided a complete test-case. It demonstrates the corruption of the document. If I hit Enter somewhere in between, then everything is ok, but if I hit Enter exactly at the last line, then I see some corruption

Comment: Obviously, I could do something wrong. My main aim was to adjust CodeMirror instance to the full height of the parent object. In this case neither hard-coded styling, nor fullScreen option works.

Comment: That is not self-contained HTML. For one, even after hunting down CDN links for the extjs junk, I don't see any tabpanel.

Comment: I should have said `toolbar`. Not `tabpanel`

Comment: Is that the blue bar? And do you mean by 'corrupted' that it overlays the editor? I have no idea what the ExtJS code is supposed to do, but I do believe it is unfair to call what is happening here a bug in CodeMirror.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that blue bar. I do not think that it is because of some hidden bug in `extjs`. The fact is, by hitting Enter button the whole instance moves up by one extra line and corrupts elements. Though, I do not insist.